# How do I enforce that a coupling table between two subtables reference the same master table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-modeling

I have one table `person` and two tables `foo` and `bar` that both reference `person` with foreign keys named `person_id`. I need to create a coupling table that links one `foo` to one `bar`, but both need to reference the same `person`.

How can I express this in a relational structure using just declarative constructs? Or do I need to create a trigger to enforce this?

```
CREATE TABLE person
(id int primary key, name text);

INSERT INTO person
(id, name)
VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Jane');

CREATE TABLE foo
(id int primary key, person_id int references person(id) not null, comment text);

INSERT INTO foo
(id, person_id, comment)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'John is great'),
(2, 2, 'Jane is great');

CREATE TABLE bar
(id int primary key, person_id int references person(id) not null, comment text);

INSERT INTO bar
(id, person_id, comment)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'John is super great'),
(2, 2, 'Jane is super great');

CREATE TABLE foo_bar
(id int primary key, foo_id int references foo(id), bar_id int references bar(id));

INSERT INTO foo_bar
(id, foo_id, bar_id)
VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2), -- Shouldn't be possible!
(3, 2, 1), -- Shouldn't be possible!
(4, 2, 2);
```

As this query demonstrates, it's perfectly possible to get results where a row in `foo_bar` references data for both John and Jane:

```
select foo.comment, bar.comment from foo_bar
inner join foo ON foo.id = foo_bar.foo_id
inner join bar ON bar.id = foo_bar.bar_id;
```

Result:

```
John is great, John is super great
John is great, Jane is super great
Jane is great, John is super great
Jane is great, Jane is super great
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/40c78/3

Comment: Why do you need `foo_bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a unique constraint on `foo` and `bar` that contains the `id` as well as `person_id`. If the foreign key constraints on `foo_bar` reference these unique constraints, the condition is automatically satisfied.

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_id_person_unique
   UNIQUE (person_id, id);
ALTER TABLE bar ADD CONSTRAINT bar_id_person_unique
   UNIQUE (person_id, id);

ALTER TABLE foo_bar ADD person_id integer;

UPDATE foo_bar
SET person_id = foo.person_id
FROM foo
WHERE foo_bar.foo_id = foo_id;

ALTER TABLE foo_bar ALTER person_id SET NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE foo_bar ADD CONSTRAINT foo_bar_foo_fkey
   FOREIGN KEY (person_id, foo_id) REFERENCES foo (person_id, id);
ALTER TABLE foo_bar ADD CONSTRAINT foo_bar_bar_fkey
   FOREIGN KEY (person_id, bar_id) REFERENCES bar (person_id, id);
```

Then drop the original foreign key constraints from `foo_bar`.

I would *not* use an artificial primary key for `foo_bar`, since `(foo_id, bar_id)` is a natural primary key that would guarantee that no relationship is entered more than once.

Comment: Very smart! `id` is defined as the primary key and thus `id` in combination with any other field is also implicitly unique, but is the unique constraints still needed because of technical reasons?

Comment: Yes, a foreign key constraint must point to a primary or a unique key. That's the down side with this solution: two extra indexes. You could also include `person_id` in the primary key, even if that would violate the second normal form. That would save you an index.

Answer (score 1):

You have stumbled upon the main issue with single surrogate keys: when it comes to hierarchies (like foo_bar being child to both foo and bar which are both children to person), the database system cannot enforce consistency.

So work with composite keys instead. Something along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
CREATE TABLE person (person_nr, name text,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_nr));

CREATE TABLE foo (person_nr, foo_nr, comment text,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_nr, foo_nr),
  FOREIGN KEY person_nr REFERENCES person(person_nr));

CREATE TABLE bar (person_nr, bar_nr, comment text,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_nr, bar_nr),
  FOREIGN KEY person_nr REFERENCES person(person_nr));

CREATE TABLE foo_bar (person_id, foo_nr, bar_nr,
  PRIMARY KEY (person_nr, foo_nr, bar_nr),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_nr, foo_nr) REFERENCES foo(person_nr, foo_nr),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_nr, bar_nr) REFERENCES bar(person_nr, bar_nr));
```

Composite keys have the disadvantage of making joins a tad more prone to errors (i.e. you may confuse key parts or miss a part of the key), but they also make the database better by enforcing consistency.

Comment: Good answer! Unforunately, I have other constraints in my architecture that requires me to use synthetic integer primary keys, but you have a good point.